# webpage is not clickable in internet explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

The links on my project working on is not clickable on Internet Explorer but Ok on firefox and chrome. It is essential to support this on IE. I have been researching this for days. I first I put on position:fixed on the body background, but when I removed the position: fixed, my background will not be responsive. Here is the some css

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <title></title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">

    <script src="js/vendor/modernizr-2.6.2-respond-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="SpryAssets/SpryMenuBar.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <link href="SpryAssets/SpryMenuBarHorizontal.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body >
        <!--[if lt IE 7]>
            <p class="chromeframe">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> or <a href="http://www.google.com/chromeframe/?redirect=true">activate Google Chrome Frame</a> to improve your experience.</p>
        <![endif]-->
       <div id="container">
             <div id="main_corporate">
             <img id="logo" src="img/logo.png">


         <div id="content_corporate1">
             <p  >Whether you are hosting a small lunch meeting or a grand banquet, preparing for an event can be a daunting task. The venue set up, the dishes and beverages must all be carefully planned and executed to be able to provide your guests an outstanding dining experience.</p>
             <p >Save yourself from all these work and engage a seasoned caterer to do everything for you! Occasions Catering is a full-service caterer that has been delivering unique and exceptional culinary experiences since 2006.</p>
             <p  >Occasions Catering represents the best culinary experience in Singapore. We are with our clients from the conceptualization of the ideas to the smooth delivery of the event.From high end corporate functions to intimate gatherings, our skilled kitchen and operation teams continuously astonish clients with detailed setups, appetizing meals and first class service.</p>
             <p style="margin-right:90px" >Don't just take our word for it. Request for a food tasting session today! </p>

           </div>

           <div id="socialmed">
      <a href=" http://www.facebook.com/OccasionsSG"><img src="img/facebook.png" ></a>
      <a href="http://www.twitter.com/OccasionsSG"><img src="img/twitter.png"></a>
        <a href="http://instagram.com/occasionscateringsg"><img src="img/instagram.png"></a>
      <img src="img/youtube.png">
    </div>            

         <ul id="MenuBar1" class="MenuBarHorizontal2">
           <li style="width:70px;"><a href="home.html" >HOME</a></li>
           <li><a href="aboutus.html" >ABOUT US</a></li>        
         </ul>
     </div> 
     <div id="footer" class="clearfix">

              <div class="about1">
                <a href="http://occasionscateringsg.wordpress.com"></a>
            </div>
           <div class="about2">
                <a href="http://eepurl.com/FMnz1"></a>
            </div>
             <div class="about3">
                <a  href="http://on-ah-catering.sg"></a>
            </div>
         </div>     
  </div>




        <script>
var _gaq=[['_setAccount','UA-XXXXX-X'],['_trackPageview']];
            (function(d,t){var g=d.createElement(t),s=d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0];
            g.src='//www.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
            s.parentNode.insertBefore(g,s)}(document,'script'));
var MenuBar1 = new Spry.Widget.MenuBar("MenuBar1", {imgDown:"SpryAssets/SpryMenuBarDownHover.gif", imgRight:"SpryAssets/SpryMenuBarRightHover.gif"});
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the jsfiddle of the complete code: http://jsfiddle.net/jethph/TKM9Y/. Sorry for untidy code.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: In case of IE issue please use http://jsbin.com/ and not  http://jsfiddle.net/ is not compatible with IE8.

Comment: Ive checked in IE8 but I think there will be issue on IE 6 and 7 and they want it in IE6.. :(

Comment: Here is the jsbin: http://jsbin.com/UNoReta/2/edit?html,css,output

Comment: @JethroGamad IE6? Tell them support for IE6 costs extra.